# How to find element from react-native app using appium - React Native + Appium

Tags: selenium, react-native, xpath, appium

How to find element in React-Native app using appium. Here the element does not have id, name or accessibility label or accessibility id to find it.

```
@AndroidFindBy(xpath = "//android.widget.EditText[@text='Email']")
public AndroidElement edt_email_login;

@AndroidFindBy(xpath = "//android.widget.EditText[@text='Password']")
public AndroidElement edt_password_login;

@AndroidFindBy(xpath = "//android.widget.EditText[@text='Login']")
public AndroidElement btn_login;
```

Error:

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Can't locate an element by this strategy: By.chained({By.xpath: //android.widget.EditText[@text='Login']})
    at io.appium.java_client.pagefactory.AppiumElementLocator.findElement(AppiumElementLocator.java:126)
    at io.appium.java_client.pagefactory.interceptors.InterceptorOfASingleElement.intercept(InterceptorOfASingleElement.java:59)
    at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidElement$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$b598166c.click(<generated>)
    at LoginTest.TestCase1(LoginTest.java:19)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:124)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:583)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:719)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:989)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:648)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:505)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:455)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:450)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:415)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:364)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:84)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1208)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1137)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1049)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1017)
    at org.testng.IDEARemoteTestNG.run(IDEARemoteTestNG.java:73)
    at org.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:123)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for io.appium.java_client.pagefactory.AppiumElementLocator$WaitingFunction@18bc345 (tried for 1 second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.timeoutException(FluentWait.java:304)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.until(FluentWait.java:272)
    at io.appium.java_client.pagefactory.AppiumElementLocator.waitFor(AppiumElementLocator.java:99)
    at io.appium.java_client.pagefactory.AppiumElementLocator.findElement(AppiumElementLocator.java:119)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Cannot locate an element using By.chained({By.xpath: //android.widget.EditText[@text='Login']})
For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'AGILEPC-146', ip: '192.168.157.2', os.name: 'Windows 8.1', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.3', java.version: '1.8.0_201'
Driver info: driver.version: AndroidDriver
    at io.appium.java_client.pagefactory.bys.builder.ByChained.findElement(ByChained.java:74)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:315)
    at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.findElement(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:58)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.findElement(AppiumDriver.java:1)
    at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.findElement(AndroidDriver.java:1)
    at io.appium.java_client.pagefactory.bys.ContentMappedBy.findElement(ContentMappedBy.java:50)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:315)
    at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.findElement(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:58)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.findElement(AppiumDriver.java:1)
    at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.findElement(AndroidDriver.java:1)
    at io.appium.java_client.pagefactory.AppiumElementLocator.lambda$0(AppiumElementLocator.java:120)
    at io.appium.java_client.pagefactory.AppiumElementLocator$WaitingFunction.apply(AppiumElementLocator.java:172)
    at io.appium.java_client.pagefactory.AppiumElementLocator$WaitingFunction.apply(AppiumElementLocator.java:1)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.until(FluentWait.java:249)
    ... 29 more
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accessing React Elements using Appium for Automation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33937898/accessing-react-elements-using-appium-for-automation)

Comment: If the element doesn't have an accessibility id then how to find it??

Comment: There are lot of other properties to find element like by name, by ID etc. Refer : http://appium.io/docs/en/commands/element/find-elements/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using Appium, do you have an AppiumDriver or AndroidDriver instance you can use?

Rather than use `@AndroidFindBy(xpath = "//android.widget.EditText[@text='Password']")
public AndroidElement edt_password_login;`, I would recommend trying something a little more simple, like this:

```
private class Selectors
{
    public static readonly By Password = By.XPath("//android.widget.EditText[@text='Password'];

    public static readonly By Email = By.XPath("//android.widget.EditText[@text='Email']");

}
```

This works around the need for @AndroidFindBy, which I think is what may be throwing the error here. You can locate your elements using the driver:

`driver.findElement(Selectors.Email);`
`driver.findElement(Selectors.Password);`